# How can I change this function so that I can call it from the parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call, children

I'm using this function to replace the standard html checkboxes and I'd like to call it from the `label for` attribute instead of the `<div>` where it's currently located.

I'm not sure how to modify it so that I can call the child `<div>` instead of `onclick="toggle_colorbox(this);"`. I'm using this for a large number of checkboxes so I don't want to call it by id.

HTML

```
<label for="color_Black"><div style="background-color: #000000" class="color" onclick="toggle_colorbox(this);"><div class=CheckMark>&#10003;</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Black" id="color_Black" class="cbx"/></div>Black</label>
```

JS

```
function toggle_colorbox(span) {
    div = span.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    cb = span.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    if (cb.checked == false) {
        div.style.visibility = "visible";
        span.className = "color ColorboxSelected";
        cb.checked = true;
    }
    else {
        div.style.visibility = "hidden";
        span.className = "color";
        cb.checked = false;
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.color { border: 1px solid silver; vertical-align:baseline; margin-right:4px; width: 1.65em; height:1.65em; font-size:8px;float:left;  }
.color input {height: 100%; width: 100%; font-size:200%;}
.ColorboxSelected {opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity = 50);}  
.ColorboxSelected .CheckMark {visibility: visible; }        
.CheckMark {position:relative; top:-2px; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center ; color:white; font-family: Arial Narrow; font-size:1.6em;  display:block; visibility:hidden; }   /* text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;*/
.cbx { visibility:hidden; display:none;}
```

Comment: Why is it tagged jQuery, and why isn't it tagged javascript?

Comment: I understand that this might be easier to do in jQuery. Should I re-tag it as javascript instead?

Comment: note that you shouldn't use `onclick=` if you use jQuery.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Really? Why is that?

Comment: I just want to call out that typically the "for" attribute is [used to associate a label with an input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-for)

Comment: jQuery normalises the event object that you get. It might not matter when reacting to click events, but it does help to know for sure you can use `e.which`

Comment: jQuery passes `this` as the event target. This is non-trivial to do manually (and `onclick="handler.call(this,event)"`) looks bad (IMO)

Comment: @contactmatt - Is there a reason that it shouldn't be used with other form elements (in this case checkboxes)?

Comment: Also, you don't have to remember the `event` object's name. It's the first argument, and it's named however you decide.

Comment: @ChayaCooper it can be used with checkboxes

Comment: @iAmClownShoe - You lost me with some of the terminology :-( Would you mind clarifying what you mean?

Comment: @ChayaCooper which term do you need explaining?

Comment: another reason to not use `onclick` is that `onclick` is `eval`. We all hate `eval`

Comment: @JanDvorak, Yes you can, but again this is usually done with <input type="checkbox"> checkboxes, not custom ones.  But that's not a big deal, however, IMO the HTML is poorly constructed.  When using a <label> element with a "for" attribute in conjunction with an input, it doesn't wrap the <input> element, it sits next to it.  (See the w3.org link in my previous comment)

Comment: @contactmatt actually, you _can_ wrap a `label` around an `input` in HTML. Then you leave out the `for` attribute.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I didn't know that you can leave out the for if you wrap it in the label :-) That'll save me some time :-D

Comment: HTML lets you do all sorts of crazy stuff like leave out half of the tags. That's why it's so hard to parse manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call it from the label you can get the child DIV like this...

```
<label for="color_Black" onclick="toggle_colorbox(this.children[0]);">
```

Comment: I discovered that this is causing another function - one which shows in another container the values selected - to stop working properly :-( (It's adding every value 2x every time it's either checked or unchecked) Any suggestions for how I can correct that? Each element is a list item, and the function I'm having a problem with is: $(".dropdown_container ul li a").click(function () {
var text = $(this).find("input").val();
    var currentHtml = $(".dropdown_box span").html();
    $(".dropdown_box span").html(currentHtml.replace('Colors',''));
    $(".dropdown_box span").append(text);
});

Comment: I resolved this thanks to another awesome SO member: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15263557/1056713. I chose this answer for it's simplicity (@SimonC's approach is quite elegant, and a definite upvote, but a little above my skill set for when I'll need to modify it).

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following. This would set up the toggle function to fire on click of any label with the class `toggle`. It would look for the div and checkbox directly within that label.

HTML:

```
<label class="toggle" for="color_Black"><div style="background-color: #000000" class="color"><div class=CheckMark>&#10003;</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Black" id="Checkbox1" class="cbx"/></div>Black</label>
```

JS:

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function toggle_colorbox() {
    $div = $(this).children('div');
    $cb = $(this).find('input');
    $innerdiv = $div.find('div');

    if (!$cb.is(':checked')) {    
        $innerdiv.show();
        $div.addClass("ColorboxSelected");
        $cb.prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $innerdiv.hide();
        $div.removeClass("ColorboxSelected");
        $cb.prop('checked', false);
    }
    return false;

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLJwH/1/

EDIT: Answer now featuring working code!

Comment: This is definitely what I'm trying to do, but I'm having trouble getting this code to work properly :-( In the fiddle you posted the entire colorbox is hidden when I doubleclick on it, and for some reason it doesn't work at all when I copy and paste it into a document.

Comment: :-D 2 slight problems - The new fiddle works perfectly when you click on the text, but doesn't work when you click on the colorbox. Also, I discovered that this is causing another function - one which shows in another container the values selected - to stop removing values when they've been unchecked :-( Would you mind taking a look at this fiddle which has both functions? http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/aLJwH/5/

Comment: Works for me when clicking on the color box in Chrome and FF. How about this for the box showing what is selected? http://jsfiddle.net/aLJwH/6/

Comment: You're absolutely right about the other browsers - I checked it in Chrome, Safari & IE and it works in those, but it's weird that it doesn't work for me in FF (v. 18.0.2) :-( Do you think it's the particular version that would be the issue?

Comment: The solution you posted to remove the values is great :-) Unfortunately the code you used is a bit more advanced than I am, so I'm having trouble figuring out where to adjust things to modify the function or integrate it with the rest of the code (ie. replacing strings to format the values displayed, or using length to evaluate the # of options checked), or when I want to do something similar elsewhere. Would you be able to explain me to me how the new fields correlate to the fields I was using previously (or if it’s easier, separate the dropdown_container values back into its own function)?

Comment: Possibly. Not 100% sure though. I'm on v19.

Comment: Your approach is really quite elegant and it makes me wish that I was more advanced so that I could use. Unfortunately it's a little above my skill set for me to integrate it into the rest of my code so I'm going to use @DamonFriendship's solution. I'm incredibly grateful for all your help, and I wish that I could do more than just an upvote (it's times like these that I wish SO allowed accepting more than one answer ;-) )